# How to stop the thread by pressing the toggle button

Tags: android, multithreading

```
private static final int SERVERPORT = 23; //port ng tcp
// String SERVER_IP ="0";
private static String SERVER_IP = "192.168.0.22";
```

this is the toggle button listener to connect how to stop the thread when pressing the toggle button and disonnect when pressing it again

```
cbtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)` {
            if(isChecked){
                tv1.setEnabled(false);
                try {
                        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            } else {
                try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    tv1.setEnabled(true);
                    //   MainActivity.SERVER_IP = tv1.getText().toString();
                    // thread.destroy();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), SERVER_IP,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

> This is the thread CLientThread and how may i change the value of SERVER_IP if it is a static ?

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           try {
               InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
               socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
           } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Thread.stop() has been deprecated since it is inherently unsafe. One way to achieve your intended behavior is to interrupt the thread. More information can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

You can do following:

```
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    private Thread client; 
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)` {
            if(isChecked){
                tv1.setEnabled(false);
                try {
                        client = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                        client.start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            } else {
                try {
                        socket.close();
                        client.interrupt();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  ...
            }
        }
    });
```

For your second question:

> how may i change the value of SERVER_IP if it is a static ?

Its quite straight forward. Just reassign:

`SERVER_IP= <new ip address>`

Since `SERVER_IP`is not final.

However I would recommend you not to do this since its not a good practice and could have impact while debugging.